# Zapier to open exe / Zapier Code to open javascript that opens exe

Tags: javascript, automation, exe, zapier

I want to open an exe file that I've created from my PC (it's safe), I looked at Zapier Apps and Zapier Code seems like the way to do it. I want a javascript code to open an exe file in my PC. 
Javascript is in path E:\New folder\code.jsx
exe file is in path E:\New folder\program.jsx

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Unfortunately, that's not possible. Zapier runs in the cloud and can't directly access your computer (nor any of the files on it).

Comment: Thank you David for your reply, but Zapier Code can run a javascript (not from my computer - directly copied to Zapier), right?

And theoretically inside the javascript I can open the exe I want from my computer? that is some kind of a workaround

Comment: While Zapier can run any javascript code you like, it still can't access anything on your local machine. If you were very motivated, you could run a local webserver and use `ngrok` so there's a tunnel open. I'm not sure if a webserver can run an exe though.